# How to create an api request in python with apy key

Tags: python, django, api, postman

I need to make an api call with api key in django  ,this works in postman :

[image]

i have tried it in python :

```
header={"content-type": "application/json","Authorization": "X-Api-Key %s" %(self.api_key)}

r = requests.post(email_meta_path,json=json,header=header)
```

but i got authentication credintionals error , how can i create the postman request in python ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the code snippet option in Postman (Located on the right-hand side, usually minimised);

[image]

Select the language you want to use and it should give you the code from your request;

[image]